# How to detected which input fields in my formGroup is on blur, Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form with formgroup, I put blur event on every input on my form.

How can i detect which specific inputs on blur ??

html file:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='bankAccountNumber' (blur)="updateCompanyInfo($event)" required>

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='phoneNumber' (blur)="updateCompanyInfo($event)" required>
```

ts file :-

```
  updateCompanyInfo($event) {

  }
```

Comment: Its blur and not blue

Comment: I wrote this quickly on the site and made a mistake

Comment: Fine as given in my ans you can use a second parameter. Or if you dont need  $event replace it with respective formcontrols

Comment: Tip: For anyone with many form inputs that **doesn't** need to know which exact form control has lost focus you can use `focusout()` and `focusin()` event on a parent container (div / section) to get notified when any input focus changes. `focusout` bubbles whereas `blur` does not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='bankAccountNumber' (blur)="updateCompanyInfo($event, bankAccountNumber)" required>

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='phoneNumber' (blur)="updateCompanyInfo($event, phoneNumber)" required>
```

Take the second parameter if you want to use some logic.

If it's just assigning then no need to do anything as formcontrol will have the respective value

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to achieve that is to add an extra paramater to the handler, like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='bankAccountNumber' (blur)="updateCompanyInfo('bankAccountNumber', $event)" required>

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='phoneNumber' (blur)="updateCompanyInfo('phoneNumber', $event)" required>
```

in the handler

```
updateCompanyInfo(formControlName, $event) {
  switch(formControlName) {
  case 'bankAccountNumber':
    // do something
  break;
  case 'phoneNumber':
    // do something
  break;
  }
}
```